# The scope in simulink drops first few data

Tags: scope, simulation, simulink

I have a simulation set to run for 30 seconds, with several scopes. The problem is that the output for the first 20 seconds of the run is dropped by the scopes at the end of the simulation run.

If I want to see these outputs, I would have to change the 'stop time' in configuration parameters to 20 seconds. My 'start time' is always set at 0.0 seconds.

Is there any place where I can change the buffer setting or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the scope block will only display the last 5000 data points.  As described in the [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/scope.html) for the scope block, you can adjust this setting by navigating to the History tab of the scope's parameters dialog box.  There you will see the setting *Limit data points to last*.  You can either increase the number of data points that are displayed, or simply uncheck this setting to allow all data points to be displayed.  Because you are running your simulation over such a short span of time, it's probably perfectly fine to just uncheck this setting on each of your scopes.